# How to prevent registering notification settings twice?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uilocalnotification

I am registering notification settings in my `AppDelegate.didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` event like this:

```
let notificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
let acceptAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
acceptAction.identifier = "Accept"
acceptAction.title = "Accept"
acceptAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background
acceptAction.destructive = false
acceptAction.authenticationRequired = false

let declineAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
declineAction.identifier = "Decline"
declineAction.title = "Decline"
declineAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background
declineAction.destructive = false
declineAction.authenticationRequired = false

let category = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
category.identifier = "invite"
category.setActions([acceptAction, declineAction], forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Default)
let categories = NSSet(array: [category])
let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationType, categories: categories)
application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
```

How do I prevent my app from registering this twice in case the user exits the app and returns later, or is it harmless to re-register multiple times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once a user has been prompted once for notifications, they will not be asked again. You can verify this for yourself in Simulator. Therefore, the code there is fine as-is.

Comment: Well I have a tutorial, so I register the notifications after the tutorial finishes. I have a couple places where I am registering the notifications, in case they skip the tutorial. So I'm wondering is calling this code multiple times throughout my all is a problem?

Comment: iOS will only ever present the prompt once. You can invoke it as many times as you want.